# How to debug sidekiq failed job?

Tags: devise, sidekiq

The sending job pass to sidekiq successfully.

However, it goes to failed directly instead of retry or dead.

I don't know how to debug this problem.

I try to use gem 'sidekiq-failures'. But I still can't see failed job.

I also try to use gem 'sentry-raven'. But i can't see any fail logs.

Please help me~

Answer (score 0):

I use `ps aux | grep sidekiq`

I found that there are 2 sidekiq processes.

I kill all processes and restart sidekiq

this problem is solved.

But now ... I have another problem，why mails are stucking at enqueued after deployment.